# Created simple table with for-loop python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

Im just trying to create simple table with following this code

```
n = 0
x = ["list1","list2","list3","list4"]
for y in x:
    n+=1
    h="{}. {}".format(n,y) + '   ' + "{}. {}".format(n+n,y)
    print(h)
```

And output i got

```
1. list1  5. list1
2. list2 6. list2
3. list3  7. list3
4. list4  8. list4
```

What should i do to got output like this

```
1. list1  3. list3
2. list2  4. list4
```

Im just beginning and so confused to solved it,thanks for who can answer my issue.

Comment: This is a great problem to ask on here, however, next time try to write the title as a question or stated issue.

Comment: Can formatting help here as explained for example at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/ ?

Comment: I dont know about this format function can solved my issue,but i can read that maybe can help and thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0):

The below should give you what you are looking for, no matter how long the list is. There may be a more efficient way than this but this way breaks it down into its parts, so essentially you need to find the halfway point in the list and print the respective value on the right.

```
x = ["list1","list2","list3","list4", "list5",]

if len(x) % 2 == 1 :
    half = int((len(x) + 1) / 2)
else:
    half = int(len(x) / 2)

for i in range(half):
    if half > len(x) / 2:
        if i == half - 1:
            h = "{}. {}".format (i + 1 , x[i])
        else:
            h = "{}. {}".format (i + 1 , x[i]) + '   ' + "{}. {}".format (half + (i + 1) , x[int (len (x) / 2) + i + 1])
    else:
        h = "{}. {}".format (i + 1 , x[i]) + '   ' + "{}. {}".format (half + (i + 1), x[int (len (x) / 2) + i])
    print(h)
```

I have also taken into account lists that have an odd number of elements like the above example for `x`, which will give you the following output

```
1. list1   4. list4
2. list2   5. list5
3. list3
```

Comment: Its so great but so many space for feed,im just do simple task. but it greate for my reference! Thanks sir

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
import math
x = ["list1","list2","list3","list4", "list5", "list6", "list7"]
y = math.ceil(len(x)/2)
for i, j in enumerate(x[:math.ceil(len(x)/2)], start=1):
    try:
        print("{}. {}".format(i, j) + '     '"{}. {}".format(i+math.ceil(len(x)/2), x[y]))
    except:
        print("{}. {}".format(i, j))
    y +=1
```

Output:

```
1. list1     5. list5
2. list2     6. list6
3. list3     7. list7
4. list4
```

Comment: The output is yes,but i think it can be make simple code :)